# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath

Tags: android, flutter

Iam developing a pedometer app I am getting the below error while I am fetching the calories burnt by the user from google fit using fitness API. How can I solve this error. Can anyone please help me.

first I fetched the steps count it worked perfect but while fetching the calories only I am getting this error.

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform debug (project :cloud_firestore) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.2.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=28, org.gradle.libraryelements=classes, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Please include some code you use, so people can reproduce the issue easier.  Also, it doesn't look like you included full error log, please fix that or clarify. By the way, you can format your questions/answers on StackOverflow using Markdown, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help